# force client to send broadcast packet

Tags: wireless, broadcast

I have WiFi mesh network with more than one AP. So I want to see the clients' RSSI level for each APs to steer them to AP with better RSSI. I am curious whether I can check the RSSI by forcing them to broadcast some packets. In other words, I dont want to wait for the clients to send Broadcast packets, I want to make them send it, whenever I want. Lets say, I have full control over AP's software.

Comment: How does a layer-3 packet convey layer-1 stats? RSSI exists only at the radio interface. (AP or STA)

Comment: Why do you need them to send broadcast traffic specifically? Any traffic can be RX'd by an AP, so any unicast traffic should work just as well in the scenario described.

Comment: Here’s an interesting article on Why RSSI isn't very useful for signal measurements.
“You see the problem with trying to make meaningful conclusions with what amounts to a total pile of crap as a basis?”  [link](http://tomatousb.org/tut:measuring-rssi-with-wifi-cards)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably force your peers to send ARP or ND packets by sending a gratuitious ARP with their address.

This, however, is not the approach usually taken — most mesh networking daemons send broadcast or multicast packets periodically (these are typically known as "Hello" packets, and are compulsory in OLSR(v2) and Babel, and optional in DYMO/AODVv2).

Note further that RSSI is a poor predictor of link quality, at least for 802.11.  You'll find a good discussion of related issues in the [Minstrel](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/mac80211/RateControl/minstrel) litterature.